# Transform RSS-Feed into another "standard" XML-Format with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, transformation

quick question: I need to transform a default RSS Structure into another XML-format.

The RSS File is like....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>Name des RSS Feed</title>
            <description>Feed Beschreibung</description>
            <language>de</language>
            <link>http://xml-rss.de</link>
            <lastBuildDate>Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT</lastBuildDate>
            <item>
                <title>Titel der Nachricht</title>
                <description>Die Nachricht an sich</description>
                <link>http://xml-rss.de/link-zur-nachricht.htm</link>
                <pubDate>Sat, 1. Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
                <guid>01012000-000000</guid>
            </item>
            <item>
                <title>Titel der Nachricht</title>
                <description>Die Nachricht an sich</description>
                <link>http://xml-rss.de/link-zur-nachricht.htm</link>
                <pubDate>Sat, 1. Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
                <guid>01012000-000000</guid>
            </item>
            <item>
                <title>Titel der Nachricht</title>
                <description>Die Nachricht an sich</description>
                <link>http://xml-rss.de/link-zur-nachricht.htm</link>
                <pubDate>Sat, 1. Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
                <guid>01012000-000000</guid>
            </item>
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

...and I want to extract only the item-elements (with childs and attributes) XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<item>
    <title>Titel der Nachricht</title>
    <description>Die Nachricht an sich</description>
   <link>http://xml-rss.de/link-zur-nachricht.htm</link>
   <pubDate>Sat, 1. Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
   <guid>01012000-000000</guid>
</item>
...
```

It hasn't to be stored into a file. I need just the output.

**edit:** Furthermore you need to know: The RSS File could have dynamic numbers of items. This is just a sample. So it has to be looped with while, for, for-each, ...

I tried different approaches with DOMNode, SimpleXML, XPath, ... but without success.

Thanks
chris

Comment: I have posted a reply below incase you hadn't noticed. It should explain all :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach would be to use an XSLT:

```
$xsl = <<< XSL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<items>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//item">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy-of>
</items>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;
```

The above stylesheet has just one rule, namely deep copying all `<item>` elements from the source XML to an XML file and ignore everything else from the source file. The nodes will be copied into an `<items>` element for root node. To process this, you'd do

```
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();           // create Doc for XSLT
$xslDoc->loadXML($xsl);                // load stylesheet into it
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();           // create Doc for RSS
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);                // load your XML/RSS into it
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();           // init XSLT engine
$proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);      // load stylesheet into engine
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);   // output transformed XML
```

Instead of outputting, you could just write the return value to file.

Further reading:

- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copy-of

Comment: i will try it tomorrow and give you feedback.
didn't thought about an xslt approach - thanks for this!

Comment: Hey Gordon, where have I to include (or reference) to my given RSS-File? I'm asking, because in the PHP-Part you wrote in the fourth comment "load your xml/rss", but the var $xml is already used for the XSL above. - XSL is pretty new stuff for me, so I guess I'm still thinking too complex.

edit: Okay, I am blind or still tired. I didn't see there are two different vars ($xml and $xsl). - Let's give it a try ;)

Comment: @Chris you can assign the `$xml` var the same way you assign the `$xsl` with HEREDOC syntax. Or use `->load('filename.xml')`.

Comment: Hm, are you sure you didn't forget something? Because I don't get any output.

Comment: Yea it works. My fault..had a silly typo in my code. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is hardly a transformation. You are basically just extracting the `<item>` elements as they are. Also, the result you give is not valid XML, as it lacks a root node.

Apart from that, you can simple do it like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;           // init new DOMDocument
$dom->loadXML($xml);              // load some XML into it

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);      // create a new XPath
$nodes = $xpath->query('//item'); // Find all item elements
foreach($nodes as $node) {        // Iterate over found item elements
    echo $dom->saveXml($node);    // output the item node outerHTML
}
```

The above would echo the `<item>` nodes. You could simply buffer the output, concatenate it to a string, write to it an array and implode, etc - and write it to file.

If you want to do it properly with DOM (and a root node), the full code would be:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;                          // init DOMDocument for RSS
$dom->loadXML($xml);                             // load some XML into it

$items = new DOMDocument;                        // init DOMDocument for new file
$items->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;              // dump whitespace
$items->formatOutput = TRUE;                     // make output pretty
$items->loadXML('<items/>');                     // create root node

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);                     // create a new XPath
$nodes = $xpath->query('//item');                // Find all item elements
foreach($nodes as $node) {                       // iterate over found item nodes
    $copy = $items->importNode($node, TRUE);     // deep copy of item node
    $items->documentElement->appendChild($copy); // append item nodes
}
echo $items->saveXML();                          // outputs the new document
```

Instead of `saveXML()`, you'd use `save('filename.xml')` to write it to a file.

Comment: thanks gordon, looks good, but i get an error message. couldn't find out what the failure is.
   "Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /home/chris/http/dev/xmlfeed/index3.php  on line 4"

Comment: @Chris I've used the RSS XML you gave for $xml. Remember, loadXML loads from a String. If you want to load from a URL or file use load() only.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$xmlFile = new DOMDocument(); //Instantiate new DOMDocument
$xmlFile->load("URL TO RSS/XML FILE"); //Load in XML/RSS file
$xmlString = file_get_contents("URL TO RSS/XML FILE"); 

$title[] = "";
$description[] = "";
$link[] = "";
$pubDate[] = "";
$guid[] = "";

for($i = 0; $i < substr_count($xmlString, "<item>"); $i++)
{
$title[] = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue; //Get the value of the node <title>
$description[] = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$link[] = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName("link")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$pubDate[] = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName("pubDate")->item(0)->nodeValue;
$guid[] = $xmlFile->getElementsByTagName("guid")->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

Untested but the arrays

$title[]
$description[]
$link[]
$pubDate[]
$guid[]

should be populated with all of the data that you need!

**EDIT:**
OK so another approach:

```
<?php
$xmlString = file_get_contents("URL TO RSS/XML FILE"); 
$titles = preg_filter("/<title>([.]*)</title>/","\\1", mixed $xmlString);
$descriptions = preg_filter("/<description>([.]*)</description>/","\\1", mixed $xmlString);
$links = preg_filter("/<link>([.]*)</link>/","\\1", mixed $xmlString);
$pubDates = preg_filter("/<pubDate>([.]*)</pubDate>/","\\1", mixed $xmlString);
$guids = preg_filter("/<guid>([.]*)</guid>/","\\1", mixed $xmlString);
?>
```

In this example each variable will be filled with the correct values.

Comment: would be kind of you, if you could extend your approach.
thanks

Comment: thank you cheif17, but it don't seem to me as a clean solution for this kind of problems. with your code, you have to pick up every single attribute and build the new xml document with the arrays.

Comment: ok i have put an edit at the bottom witha totally different approach!